# How and when is AbpSession set?

Tags: c#, .net, aspnetboilerplate

The story behind:

- I have added new field `ConnectionString` into `Tenant` class.
- I have changed `TenantCacheItem.CustomData` also, so new `ConnectionString` is also available from cache.
- I have created my own `MyDbPerTenantConnectionStringResolver: DbPerTenantConnectionStringResolver`, so it contains new method to get `"MyNewConnectionString"`. If it is host, then `MyDbPerTenantConnectionStringResolver` throws exception.

Now I have to create my own repository (it is not EF repository, but custom repository). And this repository should take `"MyNewConnectionString"` from `Tenant`. 
I know that `Tenant` information is available from `AbpSession`. But I do not understand how and when `AbpSession` should be sent to `MyRepository`.

Probably, I have to add `IAbpSession` in `MyRepository` constructor, but how to set it? Who sets `AbpSession` and when `AbpSession` actually gets value?
If I understand how this works in ASP.NET Boilerplate's `DbContext`, I could recreate the same logic in my own repository.

Comment: `IAbpSession` is created and provided by `Castle.Windsor` Inversion of Control container. So, if you request your custom repository via `Castle.Windsor`, your problem will be entirely solved by it.

Comment: By the way you can alternatively use `Setting Management` to store your tenant specific variables. https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Setting-Management

Answer (score 2):

> Probably, I have to add IAbpSession in MyRepository Constructor, but how to set it?

You can property-inject `IAbpSession`:

```cs
public class MyRepository : ITransientDependency
{
    public IAbpSession AbpSession { get; set; }

    public MyRepository()
    {
        AbpSession = NullAbpSession.Instance;
    }
}
```

> Who sets AbpSession and when AbpSession actually gets value?

`IAbpSession` is implemented as a singleton by [`ClaimsAbpSession`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/a4882aec97b9167e1ac7793dad47f7322ade353e/src/Abp/Runtime/Session/ClaimsAbpSession.cs).

Its properties are getters. For example:

```
public override long? UserId
{
    get
    {
        // ...

        var userIdClaim = PrincipalAccessor.Principal?.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == AbpClaimTypes.UserId);
        // ...

        long userId;
        if (!long.TryParse(userIdClaim.Value, out userId))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return userId;
    }
}
```